# MessageInspector message: "This message cannot support the operation because it has been copied."

Tags: .net, wcf

Here's the thing:

I have a business request that all WCF messages should have a specific header, for tracking and security reasons.

Anyway, I setup an implementation of `MessageInspector` on both the client and the service -- we control both ends so far -- and all worked well on the prototype phase.

However, today, something went awire and stopped working.

I redid the prototype from scratch and things works just fine. I'm loosing my marbles over it for the entire afternoon.

The relevant code is as follow:

```
public class DispatchEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
  public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, 
                                    EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
  {
    var mi = new MessageInspector();
    endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(mi);
  }
  // ...
}

public class DispatchMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
  public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, 
                                        IClientChannel channel, 
                                        InstanceContext instanceContext)
  {
    var index = request.Headers.FindHeader("name", "");
    if (index == -1)
      throw new MessageSecurityException("...");

    var value = request.Headers.GetHeader<Guid>(index);

    // do something with the value

    return null;
  }
  // ...
}

public class ClientEndpointBehavior : IClientEndpointBehavior
{
  public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, 
                                  ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
  {
    var mi = new ClientSecurityMessageInspector();
    clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(mi);
  }
  // ...
}

public class ClientSecurityMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
  public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, 
                                  IClientChannel channel)
  {
    request.Headers.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("name", "", Guid.NewGuid()));
    return null;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Here is the configuration for the service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="[Service Name]">
      <endpoint 
           address="" 
           binding="basicHttpBinding" 
           behaviorConfiguration="headerBehavior"
           contract="[Service Contract]"/>
      <endpoint address="mex" ... />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Default">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="headerBehavior">
        <headerBehavior headerName="token" />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name="headerBehavior" type="[Implementation Type]" />
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Analogous, the client configuration is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="[Service name]" ... >
                <readerQuotas ... />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport 
                         clientCredentialType="None" 
                         proxyCredentialType="None"
                         realm=""/>
                    <message 
                         clientCredentialType="UserName" 
                         algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint 
            address="http://.../MyService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="Default"
            contract="[Service Contract]"
            name="[Service Name]"
            behaviorConfiguration="headerBehavior" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="headerBehavior">
                <headerBehavior
                    headerName="prosper-security-token"
                    securityTokenValueService="[Implementation Type]"
                    securityTokenValueGetterMethodName="[Method Name]" />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="headerBehavior" type="[Implementation Type]" />
        </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Edited to Add**

As requested, the exception stack trace is as follows:

```
(System.ServiceModel.FaultException) This message cannot support the operation because it has been copied.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at ConsoleApplication1.UserManagementService.IUserManagement.CreateUser(String username, String password, String[] systemCodes)
   at ConsoleApplication1.UserManagementService.UserManagementClient.CreateUser(String username, String password, String[] systemCodes) in C:\Users\Paulo Santos\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PJonDevelopment\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Service References\UserManagementService\Reference.cs
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Paulo Santos\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PJonDevelopment\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs
```

**Edited to Add**

As told in one of the comments I've posted a prototype project that works here: [ServiceModel.zip](http://pjondevelopment.50webs.com/files/ServiceModel.zip)

I can't stress enough that the prototype works. The only thing I don't know is why I suddenly started getting this weird message. I don't copy the message and only deal with headers, and everywhere I search say that reading the message is a big no-no.

I dread the fact that with so many points to inspect, even replace, the entire message within **WCF** model, the architects designed with such an object that even if you look at it it goes poof.

If you're giving the opportunity to inspect, make a solid objec that can sustain the hardships of behing manipulated by anyone who wants to inspect it.

Comment: What's the exception stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a Message object can only be read once.  Try using a buffer copy:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, 
                                    IClientChannel channel, 
                                    InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
MessageBuffer buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(MaxMessageSize);
    Message requestCopy = buffer.CreateMessage();
    var index = requestCopy.Headers.FindHeader("name", "");
    if (index == -1)
        throw new MessageSecurityException("...");

    var value = requestCopy.Headers.GetHeader<Guid>(index);

    // do something with the value

    return null;
}
```

For more info, check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734675.aspx).

Comment: The problem is that the message is *NOT* reaching the server. It doesn't even leave the client. I have no bleeping idea of what's going on. I even redid the prototype from scratch, and in the prototype it works like a charm.

Comment: @Paulo: Are you sure nothing is leaving the client? (and if so how are you sure?) The stack trace suggests that the client side stack received a fault response from the server. Have you configured WCF tracing on both client and server - that's always a good first step in diagnosing any unexpected behaviour?

Comment: @Paolo: Have you confirmed that the MessageInspector is causing the problem? If you take away the MessageInspector, does everything work?

Comment: Yep. if I remove the `MI` everything works just fine. I created a prototype that works fine and I'm going to post here soon.

Answer (score 8):

Use Greg Sansoms solution but replace the original message with a copy of the original message:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, 
                                IClientChannel channel, 
                                InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(MaxMessageSize);
Message requestCopy = buffer.CreateMessage();
var index = requestCopy.Headers.FindHeader("name", "");
if (index == -1)
    throw new MessageSecurityException("...");

var value = requestCopy.Headers.GetHeader<Guid>(index);

// do something with the value

//make sure the orignal message is set to a value wich has not been copied nor read
request = buffer.createMessage();

return null;
```

}

be sure to pass the request object by ref

Comment: `request = buffer.createMessage();` is ***very important***