# WCF : This message cannot support the operation because it has been copied

Tags: c#, wcf

```
private static string ReadDefaultMessageBody(ref Message message)
{
    const string XmlReaderName = "binary";

    if (message.IsEmpty)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    MessageBuffer buffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
    try
    {
        // Copy the original message and use it for reading.
        Message messageCopy = buffer.CreateMessage();

        // Re-create original message  
        message = buffer.CreateMessage();

        // Dump payload from original message  
        // It is in either plain text or in base64 encoded string  
        using (var reader = messageCopy.GetReaderAtBodyContents())
        {
            return string.Compare(reader.Name, XmlReaderName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
                            ? Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(reader.ReadInnerXml()))
                            : reader.ReadOuterXml();
        }                
    }
    finally
    {
        buffer.Close();
    }
}
```

I referred some links on stackoverflow : [This message cannot support the operation because it has been copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518941/this-message-cannot-support-the-operation-because-it-has-been-copied)

and

[MessageInspector message: "This message cannot support the operation because it has been copied."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869204/messageinspector-message-this-message-cannot-support-the-operation-because-it)

From the first link it seems like that the message cannot be copied more than once. And from the second link it seems like the message can be copied more than once if we recreate the message.

Can someone point to the mistake that i am doing. Since this method is called more than once and i get the following error : "This message cannot support the operation because it has been copied"

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: This message cannot support the operation because it has been copied.\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32 maxBufferSize)

Comment: i think its because youre calling the buffer.createMessage(); twice.
why not use message = messageCopy  instead?

Comment: Updated my question with stacktrace : Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: This message cannot support the operation because it has been copied.\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32 maxBufferSize). It has something to do with the CreateBufferedCopy more than once on the same message

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
MessageBuffer buffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
    message = buffer.CreateMessage();

    var copy = buffer.CreateMessage();
```

As explained on the original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10284173/5063263)

> The message variable is passed into your code by reference and
>   contains the message WCF will work with. It cannot be in a "already
>   read" state to be valid for WCF use. You can, however, call
>   buffer.CreateMessage() multiple times to create clones of the actual
>   message WCF is working with. If you want to inject something into the
>   existing message, you can create a new message from the old message
>   and pass the modified message back to WCF

Comment: Isn't that same thing i am doing in the code in the question above? The issue is that it cannot call CreateBufferedCopy more than once.  also the error says "This message cannot support the operation because it has been copied". I am able to read the message more than once that is not an issue

Comment: You{re doing it the other way around youre calling copy=message.createbuffer instead of message = buffer.createMessage() i think that may be it.

Comment: Also while debugging i realized one more thing that there are two concurrent threads trying to call the same method and since message is passed as a reference it is causing the issue i guess

Comment: Also did you read the answer that i linked? it really looks that its the same problem as yours.

Comment: Yes i did read the answer that u posted and the issue that is mentioned over there is that it is read more than once. For me it is copied more than once issue. Also where did u see in my code that i am doing copy=message.createbuffer

Comment: sorry i meant: messageCopy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97566/discussion-between-stackoverflowveryhelpful-and-ivan).

Comment: not working in `BeforeSendReply` for ***IDispatchMessageInspector*** ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,It works for me

```
      var bufferedMessage = message.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);

      using (var messageToRead = bufferedMessage.CreateMessage())
      {
        //Code Block
        messageToRead.Close();       
      }
      
      message = bufferedMessage.CreateMessage();
```